# What is the term for the first N elements of a list?

Tags: list, functional-programming, terminology

The first element of a list is called a head, and the rest of a list is its tail. But what is the term for a sublist that consists of first N elements of a list? And what is the name for the rest of the list after N'th element?

Comment: Really? I thought the first element of a list was called the car, the rest was called the cdr, and the list after the Nth element was called the nthcdr.

Comment: @DourHighArch Love how lisps name things. I mean, head and tail? Come on, what is this, an anatomy class?

Jokes aside, nthcdr is a valid answer for the second part of the question.

Comment: You could call it *the prefix of length n*.

Comment: Not all concepts have established names, but the Haskell documentation for `take` and `drop` call these "prefix" and "suffix".

Comment: @DourHighArch When you know you are doing list stuff using `list*`,`first`, and `rest` instead of `cons`, `car`, and `cdr` makes the code more clear. When it comes to denote two parts of a pair `car` and `cdr` seem to be the best names as I haven't seen any better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in a rather large subset of linked list implementations, the tail is actually the *last* element rather than the list sans the head :-)

Since there appears to be little consensus (after two years) as to what you should call the initial subset, you can name it whatever you like as long as it's clear, for example:

- initial subset of size N;
- first N elements;
- initial-N.

I would actually call the *rest* of the list just the remainder, since you'll almost always be using it in the context of what you're discussing.

So, for example, the head has a remainder of all but the head, and the initial subset of size `N` has a remainder of the list minus those `N` elements.